# Open a JProgressbar inside an actionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jprogressbar

I am trying to do a ProgressBar inside an actionPerfomed (I have an interface with a button to browse a folder and a run button). The objective is to initiate the progressbar after pressing the run button, but when the window appears it came all blank.

I have this code to initiate the window with browse and run button:

```
final JFrame frame_project = new JFrame("PROJECT 22");
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame_project.setSize(400,250);
    frame_project.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("Browse");
    button2.setBounds(30, 30, 90, 25);
    panel.add(button2);

    final JButton buttonStartCompare = new JButton();
    buttonStartCompare.setText("RUN");
    buttonStartCompare.setBounds(100, 80, w/2, h/2);
    panel.add(buttonStartCompare);
    frame_project.setVisible(true);
```

Then, inside the action perfomed I have this:

```
    buttonStartCompare.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JProgressBar it = new JProgressBar();
             frame_project.setVisible(false);
             JFrame frame = new JFrame("Progress Bar");
             JPanel panel = new JPanel();
             frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             panel.add(it);
             frame.setContentPane(it);
             frame.pack();
             frame.setSize(250,100);
             frame.add(panel);
             frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

EDIT:

This is the complete code after seen in Oracle. The first "ProgressMonitorDemo.createAndShowGUI();" is Ok the second is not ok:

```
final JButton Button_Run = new JButton();
    Button_Run.setText("RUN");
    Button_Run.setBounds(140, 80, 100, 100);
    panel.add(Button_Run);

    ProgressMonitorDemo.createAndShowGUI();

    Button_Run.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            Button_Run.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));

            if(fieldSheetsDirectory.getText().isEmpty()){
                JFrame frame_missing = PanelUtils.getErrorPanel("Please select the files ");
                Button_Run.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
                frame_missing.setVisible(true);
                return;
            }

            final String path = fieldSheetsDirectory.getText();

            fieldPathRapport.setText("\\Rapport.xlsx");
            fieldPathOriginal.setText("\\Original.xlsx");
            fieldPathCartoo.setText("\\MyCarto draft V2.xlsx");

            long lStartTime_open = System.currentTimeMillis();

            String path_Raportt = path.concat(fieldPathRapport.getText());
            String path_Original = path.concat(fieldPathOriginal.getText());
            String path_MyCartoo = path.concat(fieldPathCartoo.getText());

            System.out.println(path);
            System.out.println("");

            XSSFWorkbook OriginalBook = FileUtils.OpenFile(path_Original);
            XSSFWorkbook RapportBook = FileUtils.OpenFile(path_Raportt);
            XSSFWorkbook MyCartoBook = FileUtils.OpenFile(path_MyCartoo);

            if(OriginalBook == null || RapportBook == null || MyCartoBook == null){
                return;
            } else {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }



            //JFrame frame_sucess = PanelUtils.getFinalErrorPanel("Running...");
            //frame_sucess.setVisible(true);
            ProgressMonitorDemo.createAndShowGUI();
```

Comment: You have no reference to a JProgresbar in your code? All you have is a JFrame that has a title "Progress Bar".

Comment: What is SwingProgressBarExample?

Comment: You have a progressbar, frame, and a panel, add the progressbar into the panel, set the progress bar as content pane of the frame, and you add the panel into the frame ? as if adding the panel into the progress bar ? now, what is on-top of what ?

Comment: The SwingProgressBarExample was basically to initiate the ProgressBar ( I have edited to be more understandable )@JamesWierzba

The panel was just a test. I guess that is not doing anything in the program... The first code is on top @FerdinandNeman

My problem is if I put the same code before the action perfomed it is all Ok. But when I put inside the action Perfomed only the frame appears.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for working examples.

Comment: @camickr I have already see that. I will put a screenshot of the code so you can see the diference. The code is exactly the same but one is outside the listener and the other is inside the listener

Comment: @camickr I don't know why, but I cannot insert images here.. I copy-paste my code to above.. The first "ProgressMonitorDemo.createAndShowGUI();" appears a totally fine window working, the second "ProgressMonitorDemo.createAndShowGUI();" appeares only the frame..